# How can a variable set in the Docker .env-File be used in application.yml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, environment-variables

I tried:
in prod.env: `HOST_PUBLIC=test.mydomain.com`

and in application-prod.yml:

```
jhipster:
...
    mail: 
        from: ...
        base-url: ${HOST_PUBLIC}
```

The variable was not recogniced and i just got ${HOST_PUBLIC} as output, same with `"${HOST_PUBLIC}"`.

I also tried with backticks base-url: `${HOST_PUBLIC}`, which made the application crash

I just want to get the correct url to build an html, which is sent to a user, to change the password.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <p>
        <a th:with="url=(@{|${baseUrl}/#/reset/finish?key=${user.resetKey}|})" th:href="${url}"
        th:text="${url}">Login link</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

at the moment the mail looks like this `${HOST_PUBLIC}/#/reset/finish?key=xxx`

Comment: Put HOST_PUBLIC=test.mydomain.com in .env file . This should be available in docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is, that variables set in .env file are only availabe for the docker-compose file and not globally like an environment variable and there not accesable from spring-application .yml file.
To make variables accessable globally I set

```
environment:
  - HOST_PUBLIC=${HOST_PUBLIC}
```

it's also possible to make the hole .env file availabe.